# How to Disable keyboard shortcuts Alt + Tab in electron app on Windows 10?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am working with Desktop Application, while I am working on Ubuntu server, I can block keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> fine, but when I'm moved to work on Windows OS and try to block <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it's not working. The most problems because of **Alt keyboard**, it's seriously didn't work on Windows 10 when I try to block it 
Here is the code That I am using:

```
var shortcutsToCapture = ['Ctrl+Alt+Delete', 'Alt+F4','CommandOrControl+A','Super+Alt+Tab','CommandOrControl+Shift+I', 'CommandOrControl+R']

// this should be placed at top of main.js to handle setup events quickly
if (handleSquirrelEvent(app)) {
    // squirrel event handled and app will exit in 1000ms, so don't do anything else
    return;
}

app.on('ready', function () {

  captureShortcuts(shortcutsToCapture)
})

function captureShortcuts(shortcuts) {
  shortcuts.forEach(function (shortcut) {
    registerShortcutCapturing(shortcut)
  })
}

function registerShortcutCapturing(shortcut) {
  var result = globalShortcut.register(shortcut, function () {
    console.log('<' + shortcut + '> captured!')
  })

  if (!result) {
    console.log('<' + shortcut + '> registration failed!')
  }
}

app.on('will-quit', () => {
  // Unregister a shortcut.
  globalShortcut.unregister('CommandOrControl+X')

  // Unregister all shortcuts.
  globalShortcut.unregisterAll()
})
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would need to prevent a user from switching to another application? The only Use-cases that I can think of involve creation of malware.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Because I am working on Online examination system so to prevent the student cheating I have to do that.

Comment: OK, that is a good reason, thank you.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts could you help me in this part?

Comment: Maybe another attempt would be to detect when the window loses focus? This way you can tell the user to not switch windows because otherwise he will fail the test. If he then does anyway, you will detect it and fail him.

Comment: @TomDoodler okay bro, thank you. I will try that.

Comment: @TomDoodler That approach will also help to stop switching tabs, or similar actions through non-keyboard approaches. I like it.

Comment: Im happy I've been able to help :)

Comment: @Tom Doodler why don't u post an answer then using [`'browser-window-blur'`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#event-browser-window-blur)  ? ;)

Comment: @TomDoodler I also try to use that one but it's not really match to the requirement.

Comment: @pergy because I didn't exactly answer OP's question, I just wanted to give him a new idea. You can post it, if you like to

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [globalShortcut](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut) module to detect keyboard events even when the application does not have keyboard focus.

```
const { app, globalShortcut } = require('electron')

app.on('ready', () => {
  globalShortcut.register('alt+tab', () => {

     return false
  })
})
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hello bro @siddharth shah it told window is not define.

Comment: @SophaSum

I found this very useful package to manage keyboard events in electronjs. this will resolve your problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-localshortcut

Comment: I already check with that link and test that code it's still not working.

Comment: @SophaSum you will need to use that in your main.js file. and also need to register for each window.

Comment: What you mean by register for each window, I also add it to main.js but it didn't work. could you give more specific.

Comment: @SophaSum i've updated the answer please check and let me know what u think of it

Comment: Thank for helping me, this code I already used it but it exactly work on linux OS but on  window the Alt keyboard, it still not working.